# Continuous autocomplete in dr racket

Tags: autocomplete, lisp, racket

I just discovered that dr. Racket has a autocomplete feature that activates when I press / + ctrl, but dissapears automatically when type a new word, and you have to press / + ctrl again.
So what i want to ask, is it possible to activate the autocomplete automatically everytime you type something, so you dont have to press / + ctrl all the time, like in the intellij IDE's?

Comment: I had a play with this and it looks like it's probably not possible without mucking around with DrRacket internals.  (This isn't an answer because it's purely guesswork and looking a bit at the sources.)

Answer (score 0):

DrRacket blue box information disappears pretty quickly unfortunately.

An alternative (with its own drawbacks) is the `Signature` script from [`quickscript-extra`](https://github.com/Metaxal/quickscript-extra):
[image]

After installing and registering quickscript-extra (see doc linked above), the script is available in the `Scripts` menu of DrRacket, or via the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+$`.

The information stays on the screen as long as it's not closed (via `Ctrl+$` again or after clicking on the cross).

Comment: A bonus of this approach is that it's much easier to modify this script alone rather than diving into the guts of DrRacket: `Scripts > Manage scripts > Library`, click on the quickscript-extra line in the left panel, then click on `def-signature` on the right panel, then `Edit`.